# run script command in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I am running a script in another directory.

Assume I have the following code:

```
arr = [10;20;30];
run(script);  % script= path to the script file + scriptfile.mat ..

x = arr(2);
```

It gave me the following error:
Undefined function 'arr' for input arguments of type 'double'.

After debugging the code, I found that run(script) .. run the script and then clear all variables .. such as arr.

Is there any way to make run command doesn't clear all variables..

Edit: the following is the original code..

```
xValues =[2;4;6];
yValues =[10;15;20;30;40];

for var1 =1:size(xValues,1)

    results =[];

    for var2 =1: size(yValues,1)

       run(strcat('C:\Users\as\Desktop\study',num2str(xValues(var1)),'folder\',num2str(yValues(var2)),'folder\file1.m'));

       results(var2,1) = yValues(var2);

    end

end
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can be sure that `script` has finish to run before the second call to `arr`?

Comment: Are you sure that the `clear` command is not invoked *inside* your script? I tried to replicate your problem, but with some dummy script it seems that everything works fine and `arr` is not cleared after the execution of the script with the `run` command.

Comment: Hi, can you show us the complete script you are trying to execute?

Comment: @Adiel yes since the commands are ordered in script also..

Comment: @UJIN yes I ma sure

Comment: @minidiable I added the original code ..

Comment: @noor The question is what is the code inside the script, not how you execute it. There is also a possibility this script doesn't have clear all, but is calling another script that has it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, erase `clear` command in your script file:

**testing.m**

```
arr = [10;20;30];
run('ScriptFile.m')
x = arr(2);
```

**ScriptFile.m**

```
disp('Hello World');
```

**Command Window**

```
Hello World
```

After the implementation `x` holds number *20*.

Comment: I tried your example and worked ! but I don't know why my code doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

It is clear all inside your script doing the mess I believe.

As for how to avoid it:

1. Simply remove it. This is generally the easiest and best solution.
2. Write file to the disk, run script, load from disk. You need a hardcoded file name.
3. Create "data_holding_function" that has persistent cell array, you load your data there and then restore it after script. You can make the function perform both loading (when you have some input) and unloading (when you don't).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this method